# Is there a better way to write update table1 where x in (select x from table2 inner join table1)?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have an sql update statement:

```
update table1 set col1='val' where id in (select t2.id
                     from table2 t2
                              inner join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id
                     where t1.col2='val2' and t2.col3='val3');
```

Is there a better way to write it? I am thinking somehow not to use join since I have the table in the update construction.

Maybe:

```
update table1 set col1='val' where id in (select t2.id
                     from table2 t2
                     where t2.col3='val3')
and t1.col2='val2';
```

Is it better the last query?

Comment: Those two UPDATE's are not guaranteed to do the same.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance,

Comment: @jarlh "Those two UPDATE's are not guaranteed to do the same. " - I thought they will do the same. The last one retrieves  all entries with the condition t2.col3='val3' and the update will occur only for those that also have t1.col2='val2'.  The first one does this filter in one step: all entries with t1.col2='val2' and t2.col3='val3'.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with `exists()` ?

```
UPDATE table1 s
SET s.col1='val'
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 t
             WHERE s.id = t.id AND someCondition)
```

Comment: I've updated the question, I am thinking that maybe there's a way on using the table1 from the update construction to not use join with table1

Comment: This query doesn't join to table1 again @anonimos . Seems to me exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I've again updated the question so that I express what I have in mind.